# Slick: update List in db

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, slick

My table schema in Postgres is the following:

[image]

I store List[String] in the 2nd column and I wrote the working method that updates this list with Union of a new list and old list:

```
  def update(userId: Long, unknownWords: List[String]) = db.run {
    for {
      y <- lists.filter(_.userId === userId).result
      words = y.map(_.unknownWords).flatMap(_.union(unknownWords)).distinct.toList
      x <- lists.filter(_.userId === userId).map(_.unknownWords).update(words)
    } yield x
  }
```

Is there any way to write this better? And maybe the question is pretty dumb, but I don’t quite understand why I should apply .result() to the first line of the for expression, the filter().map() chain on the 3d line is working fine, is there something wrong with the types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why `.result`

The reason you need to apply `.result` is to do with the difference between queries (`Query` type) and actions (`DBIO`) in Slick.

By itself, the `lists.filter` line is a query. However, the third line (the `update`) is an action. If you left the `.result` off your for comprehension would have a type mismatch between a `Query` and a `DBIO` (action).

Because you're going to `db.run` the result of the for comprehension, the for comprehension needs to result in an `DBIO` action, rather than a query. In other words, putting a `.result` there is the right thing to do because you're constructing an action to run in the database (namely, fetching some data for the user).

You'll then going to run another action later to `update` the database. So in all, you're using `for` to combine two actions (two runnable SQL expressions) into a single DBIO. That's the `x` you yield, which is executed by `db.run`.

### Better?

This is working for you, and that's just fine.

There's a small amount of duplication. You might spot your query on the first line, is *very* similar to the update query. You could abstract that out into a value:

```
val userLists = lists.filter(_.userId === userId)
```

That's a query. In fact, you could go a step further and modify the query to just select the `unknownWords` column:

```
val userUnknownWords = lists.filter(_.userId === userId).map(_.unknownWords)
```

I've not tried to compile this but that would make your code something like:

```
def update(userId: Long, unknownWords: List[String]) = {
  val userUnknownWords = lists.filter(_.userId === userId).map(_.unknownWords)
  db.run {
    for {
      y <- userUnknowlWords.result
      words = y.flatMap(_.union(unknownWords)).distinct.toList
      x <- userUnknownWords.update(words)
    } yield x
  }
```

Given that you're composing two actions (a select and an update), you could use `DBIO.flatMap` in place of the for comprehension. You might find it clearer. Or not. But here's an example...

The argument to `DBIO.flatMap` needs to be another action. That is, flatMap is a way to sequence actions. In particular, it's a way to do that while using the value from the database.

So you *could* replace the for comprehension with:

```
val action: DBIO[Int] =
  userUnknowlWords.result.flatMap { currentWords =>
      userUnknownWords.update(
        currentWords.flatMap(_.union(unknownWords)).distinct.toList
      )
  }
```

(Again, apologies for not compiling the above: I don't have the details of the types, but hopefully this will give a flavour for how the code could work).

The final `action` is the one you can pass to `db.run`. It returns the number of rows changed.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!